# Connecting a p-trap via bending the drain stem vs the trap arm?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, sink, p-trap

I have a p-trap that has an outlet that ends too close to the wall for it to be able to be connected straight into the trap adapter of the vent inside the wall.

**I'd like to avoid the non-code conforming flexible drains if at all possible.** Although it does seem like even new construction houses are being approved by building inspectors using those pipes from what I hear.

There are only 2 ideas I have:

1. Immediately at the wall trap adapter, bend the trap arm 90° (note: a 45° will run right into the drain stem), extend out a bit, and then another 90° to face the p-trap exit.
2. Immediately at the drain tailpiece, bend the drain tail piece to get further away from the wall via 2 45° fittings and then have a 'normal' straight trap arm.

The 2nd option to me seems 'cleaner' and avoids 2 immediate 90° turns like what would be required to bend the trap arm. The 2nd option also emulates the flexible pipe fitting but without the plumber purist stigma of how the crinkled edges of those pipes collects grime and clogs faster than smooth pipes.

[image: I'm all for hearing other better ideas, or perhaps anecdotal evidence that flexible fittings are becoming widely accepted by professionals and inspectors. Thanks!]

Comment: This, folks, is why you do NOT want your drain entrance dead center on your sink drain. If it's just to one side, there's a lot of available options from rotating and sliding parts. The flex pipes not only clog, they also break/crack far sooner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's standard practice to use one or more horizontal bends on the drain stub (trap arm) to gain alignment. In this case, a single 45° elbow toward the camera should do nicely. You'll swing the trap toward the camera as well to meet at an acute angle.

This image shows the wall situation I'm suggesting. Your trap will be swung the over to the right in a similar manner.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.buellinspections.com/p-traps-installing-them-properly/)</sub>

Unfortunately that may mean cutting off the existing threaded fitting (trap adapter) and replacing it upstream of the new elbow. As [Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/18078/ecnerwal) suggests, 45° double-slip elbows are also available if you don't mind a couple more compression fittings. You may even have space for a 90° elbow. Dry-fit everything so you can adjust for most efficient use of your space.